# openssl Subject Public Key Info: RSA Public Key: (1024 bit) vs Public Key: (1024 bit)

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, rsa, x509

I have a couple of certificates whose format seem pretty similar except for one thing
I have checked the details of the cert by using the following openssl command

```
openssl x509 -in certname -text
```

In one of the certificates, the Subject Public Key info appears like this

> ```
> Subject Public Key Info:
> Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
> RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)
> ```

The other looks like

> ```
> Subject Public Key Info:
> Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
> Public Key: (1024 bit)
> ```

I generated a certificate using the following command

```
openssl genrsa -out my.key 1024
openssl req -new -key my.key -config -out my.req
openssl ca -out my.crt -infiles my.req
```

My cert contains Public Key: (1024 bit) and not "RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)"

What needs to be done differently to get the "RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)" in the certificate?
My my.key starts with

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

so it's a RSA key.

Comment: try `openssl rsa -noout -text -in certname` and `openssl dsa -noout -text -in certname` on your certs. My guess is the first one is a DSA key, and it will fail with `read DSA key unable to load Key 139673943688872:error:06078081:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_get1_DSA:expecting a dsa key:p_lib.c:308:`

Comment: @dawud - `openssl rsa -in` & `openssl dsa -in` both expect a key as input - how can you read a cert with it? - As expected both commands gave me `unable to load Private Key
11984:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY`

Comment: I assumed you have both cert and key in the same file, try the commands using the file that holds the key instead

Comment: @dawud - I have the private key only for 2nd one 
(the one which doesn't give RSA Public Key) - that works fine with the `openssl rsa` command

Comment: No further guessing then, I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really compare output of the same `openssl x509` utility given different input files? The different output you ask about apparently just differs between OpenSSL versions. E.g., openssl-0.9.8e has such code:

```
                    BIO_printf(bp,"%12sRSA Public Key: (%d bit)\n","",
                    BN_num_bits(pkey->pkey.rsa->n));
```

However, openssl-1.0.0 has slightly different text:

```
            if (BIO_printf(bp,"Public-Key: (%d bit)\n", mod_len)
                    <= 0) goto err;
```

(note that the actual text is `Public-Key`, not `Public Key`). So the output for the same certificate may be different depending on which OpenSSL version you use to dump the file, and your files containing `RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)` were just dumped as text using an old version of OpenSSL.

Comment: Absolutely right. One cert was generated on a NetBSD setup I have & I got the output also on the same machine. The other was on a Windows setup. Both are different versions of openssl & the `openssl x509 -text` output differs. I ran it both on my windows setup and both look similar now. Other things which differ are Modulus size is available on one and not available on the other & the hyphen also as you noted.